# Unable to transfer new authorized_keys file from temporary instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am following the steps from: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/replacing-lost-key-pair.html#step-1-create-new-key-pair to use a new key pair to access my EC2 instance, but on step 6 running the `cp .ssh/authorized_keys /mnt/tempvol/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys` command, I am met with `.ssh/authorized_keys’ and ‘/mnt/tempvol/home/ec2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys’ are the same file`.

My root device name is /dev/xvda, and when I run `lsblk`, I see the partition xvda1 and mount that like in the instructions. I have no clue what I could be doing wrong and AWS doesn't give technical support for free personal accounts.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What is your current directory (`pwd`)? I would expect it to be `/home/ec2-user/` rather than `/mnt/tempvol/home/ec2-user`.

Comment: My working directory is ```/home/ec2-user```, the directory I am in as soon as I ssh into the temporary instance.